# Average a minute-wise time-series dataset monthly with Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have got a very large minute-wise time series dataset(for 3 months) which is in the following format

```
datetime,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12
1/06/2017 0:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.036
1/06/2017 0:01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.036
...
1/06/2017 23:59,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.035
2/06/2017 0:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.014,0,0.036
2/06/2017 0:01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.036
...
2/06/2017 23:59,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.035
....
31/08/2017 0:00,0,0.2,0,0,0,0.56,0,0,0,0.014,0,0.036
31/08/2017 0:01,0,0.23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.032
...
31/08/2017 23:59,0,0,0,0,0,0,.55,0,0,0.011,0,0.034
```

what is the most efficient way of getting the average of each column per each month using panda?
expected output would be

```
month,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12
06/2017,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.011,0,0.036
07/2017,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.014,0,0.036
08/2017,0,0,0.21,0,0,0,0,0.52,0,0.011,0,0.036
```

At the moment what I'm doing is read the dataset day by day and then get an accumulated dataset of days and then divide it by the no of days per month. But this very inefficient and take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `MS` for starts of months, last change  format of DatetimeIndex to `MM/YYY` by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

df = df.resample('MS', on='datetime').mean()
df.index = df.index.strftime('%m/%Y')
print (df)
         val1      val2  val3  val4  val5      val6      val7  val8  val9  \
06/2017   0.0  0.000000   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.000000  0.000000   0.0   0.0   
07/2017   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN   
08/2017   0.0  0.143333   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.186667  0.183333   0.0   0.0   

          val10  val11     val12  
06/2017  0.0115    0.0  0.035667  
07/2017     NaN    NaN       NaN  
08/2017  0.0120    0.0  0.034000
```

Or pass converted column of datetimes by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to `groupby` and aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')).mean()
print (df)
          val1      val2  val3  val4  val5      val6      val7  val8  val9  \
datetime                                                                     
06/2017      0  0.000000     0     0     0  0.000000  0.000000     0     0   
08/2017      0  0.143333     0     0     0  0.186667  0.183333     0     0   

           val10  val11     val12  
datetime                           
06/2017   0.0115      0  0.035667  
08/2017   0.0120      0  0.034000
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `read_csv` and `to_csv` are what you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])
df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.strftime('%m/%Y')).mean().rename_axis('month').to_csv(out, float_format='%.06f')
```

With your input data (filtered from ...) it gives:

```
month,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12
01/2017,0,0.000000,0,0,0,0.000000,0.000000,0,0,0.011000,0,0.035667
02/2017,0,0.000000,0,0,0,0.000000,0.000000,0,0,0.012000,0,0.035667
08/2017,0,0.143333,0,0,0,0.186667,0.183333,0,0,0.012000,0,0.034000
```